# Wordpress database error- #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mysql, wordpress, utf-8, longtext, mysql-error-1071

I have a WordPress blog but it has some strange characters in the content like �. I found in my phpmyadmin, that in my `wp_posts` table, the column `post_content` is using `latin1_swedish_ci` collation. I am trying to change it to `utf8_unicode_ci` but it's giving me this error:

> #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts3` CHANGE `post_content` `post_content` LONGTEXT
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
```

How can I fix it? I asked my host (hostgator) for help but they said it's not a problem from their end.

My ultimate goal is to get rid of the strange characters in my posts. Also, my wp-posts table has 33K+ rows since it's a huge blog with around 10K posts.

Comment: Collation isn't for *displaying* text. It's for ordering letters in the text. You should research why those characters are "weird", not immediately change collations and what not.